# Laravel - Data is not Fetch for some table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I try to display data in a form. Some table are successfully fetch but some table is not. I try to `'dd'` and it turns out the connection and table name is not there.

But it can fetch to whole table like this:

[image]

When I click edit button, no data is not fetch in the form like this:

[image]

and I check the URL, it is correct:

[image]

My controller:

```
public function edit(StudentApplication $student_applications)
{
    dd($student_applications);
    return view('student_application.edit', compact('student_applications'));
}
```

My Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class StudentApplication extends Model

{
use Notifiable;

 /**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

}

My View

```
<label class="form-control-label" for="student_name">{{ __('Student Name') }}</label>
<input type="text" name="student_name" id="student_name" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('student_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Student Name') }}" value="{{ old('student_name', $student_applications->student_name) }}"  required>
```

My dd result:

[image]

You can see that the connection, table and attributes are null and no data.

I did the exact same code with other module, and it works like this:

[image]

My Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateStudentApplicationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('student_applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('student_name');
            $table->bigInteger('student_ic_number');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('guardian_name');
            $table->string('guardian_ic_number');
            $table->string('phone_number');
            $table->string('relationship');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('student_applications');
}
```

}

My Route:
I put two route here, the user route is working like I show in the picture above, the studentapplication route is not working when I try to edit.

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['except' => ['show']]);
Route::resource('studentapplication', 'StudentApplicationController', ['except' => ['show']]);
```

Do you guys have a solution for my problem?

Comment: plz post your migration about this table.

Comment: This is probably a malformed route issue since the model is not correctly passed to your controller. Can we see your route file?

Comment: @TsaiKoga I put my migration in the question

Comment: @LobsterBaz Sure, I edit the question with my route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route looks incorrect.

Try this instead:

```php
Route::resource('student-applications', 'StudentApplicationController', ['except' => ['show']]);
```

Comment: isn't that differences between 'studentapplication' and 'student-application' just to determine how the url will looks like?

Comment: @lililuna it's the base URI the controller handles, I don't think it's just cosmetic but I could be wrong. Did it make a difference?

Comment: When you said about the URI controller handles, I notice that I make mistake on the base URI. You are basically correct. I pass different thing from controller to view. My silly mistake. Thank you so much